# Building GCC with MPFR, GMP and MPC

Tags: gcc, gmp, mpfr, mpc

Of course we all know building GCC version >= 4.1.x requires the supplementary packages MPFR, GMP and MPC to be present.

There's a few ways to handle these GCC dependencies:

**1)** Download and build each supporting package separately and then tell `make` where the binaries are located during GCC build time.

**2)** Download each supporting package, untar and move the source into your GCC build directory and `make` will automatically build each of the packages when needed.

(Executing the gcc-src/contrib/download_prerequisites script does the same as option 2)

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Is there an advantage to either method? Does pre-compiling the binaries provide something I'm missing by taking the "easy route" and just dumping the package's source into my GCC build directory and letting `make` figure it out?

I've seen it done more frequently in various build scripts by pre-compiling each package to a binary, and then telling `make` where they are located during gcc compilation. Is this the "preferred" way to do it? Why?

To add context, I'm mainly building cross-compilers targeting various ARM platforms.

Comment: By default, 1) would create shared libraries, and gcc might have a hard time locating them at runtime. The best and easiest by far is to get gmp/mpfr/mpc through your package manager.

Comment: @MarcGlisse getting them through the package manager is no good if you are building a portable cross-compiler, but I believe your point about creating shared libs is definitely valid in the context of portability. I'll continue to extract the source into the gcc-build directory for the time being.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For most use cases I believe that option 2 is just as good as option 1.  However, I can see a few situations in which one would want to do it manually.

- A package maintainer wants to build separately as they want separate packages for mpfr et al.
- Someone who wants to pass different configure arguments/CFLAGS to each of the packages.
- A GCC developer who wants to keep their source and build trees small as they don't make any changes to MPFR/GMP/etc.

I haven't done too much work with the (rather ugly) GCC build system, but I haven't seen any obvious differences in how the binaries are built.

I'm not the biggest authority on this though, so YMMV; I may be wrong.